# How to add animation while actionbar are changing their content with Appcompat?

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm looking at Google's Material Design guidelines and I want add animated action bar. My goal is do something like this:

[image]

How can I add transition for action bar's content? I'm using Appcompat to keep backward compatibility.

Comment: So you want actionbar icons change between navigation drawer open and close, right?

Comment: Not directly by navigation drawer. I want just animated changing of menu (for ex. when main activity's fragment are updated)

Comment: @Siper I've updated my answer that achieves the same result but is more powerful and with better modularization, check it out and let me know.

Comment: @Kai This looks so awesome! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update:

I've created an [open source library](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition) that provides transition/animation support to both View and MenuItem:

[image: MenuItem transition]
MenuItem transition

[image: View transition]
View transition

**Instructions:**

On Android Studio, add the code below to Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.github.kaichunlin.transition:core:0.8.1'
```

Sample code with explanations:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    //standard onCreate() stuff that creates set configs toolbar, mDrawerLayout & mDrawerToggle

    //Use the appropriate adapter that extends MenuBaseAdapter:
    DrawerListenerAdapter mDrawerListenerAdapter = new DrawerListenerAdapter(mDrawerToggle, R.id.drawerList);
    mDrawerListenerAdapter.setDrawerLayout(mDrawerLayout);

    //Add desired transition to the adapter, MenuItemTransitionBuilder is used to build the transition:
    //Creates a shared configuration that: applies alpha, the transition effect is applied in a cascading manner (v.s. simultaneously), MenuItems will resets to enabled when transiting, and invalidates menu on transition completion 
    MenuItemTransitionBuilder builder = MenuItemTransitionBuilder.transit(toolbar).alpha(1f, 0.5f).scale(1f, 0f).cascade(0.3f).visibleOnStartAnimation(true).invalidateOptionOnStopTransition(this, true);
    MenuItemTransition mShrinkClose = builder.translationX(0, 30).build();
    MenuItemTransition mShrinkOpen = builder.reverse().translationX(0, 30).build();
    mDrawerListenerAdapter.setupOptions(this, new MenuOptionConfiguration(mShrinkOpen, R.menu.drawer), new MenuOptionConfiguration(mShrinkClose, R.menu.main));
  }

  //Let the adapter manage the creation of options menu:
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      mDrawerListenerAdapter.onCreateOptionsMenu(this, menu);

      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

Source of the activity implementing the above is [here](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kaichunlin/transition/app/DrawerMenuItemActivity.java), and a demo app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kaichunlin.transition.app).

---

## Originally Accepted Answer:

Here's a solution that's more versatile and is exactly how the MenuItem fade-out of Google Drive, Google Docs, Google Sheets, and Google Slides work.

The advantage is that when the user slide in from the left edge of the screen to open the drawer manually, or slide right when the drawer is opened to close it, **the animation state is integrated with how the drawer is being opened/closed**.

---

***ProgressAnimator.java***: This is the meat of the implementation, it translates a float based progression value (0f~1f) into a value that Android `Animator` understands.

```
public class ProgressAnimator implements TimeAnimator.TimeListener {
    private final List<AnimationControl> animationControls = new ArrayList<>();
    private final MenuItem mMenuItem; //TODO shouldn't be here, add animation end listener
    private final ImageView mImageView;
    private final TimeAnimator mTimeAnim;
    private final AnimatorSet mInternalAnimSet;

    public ProgressAnimator(Context context, MenuItem mMenuItem) {
    if (mMenuItem == null) {
        mImageView = null;
    } else {
        mImageView = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_animation, null).findViewById(R.id.menu_animation);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(mMenuItem.getIcon());
    }
    this.mMenuItem = mMenuItem;
    this.mInternalAnimSet = new AnimatorSet();

    mTimeAnim = new TimeAnimator();
    mTimeAnim.setTimeListener(this);
    }

    public void addAnimatorSet(AnimatorSet mAnimSet, float start, float end) {
    animationControls.add(new AnimationControl(mImageView, mAnimSet, start, end));
    }

    public void addAnimatorSet(Object target, AnimatorSet mAnimSet, float start, float end) {
    animationControls.add(new AnimationControl(target, mAnimSet, start, end));
    }

    public void start() {
    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(new Object() {
        private int dummy;

        public int getDummy() {
        return dummy;
        }

        public void setDummy(int dummy) {
        this.dummy = dummy;
        }
    }, "dummy", 0, 1);
    colorAnim.setDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    mInternalAnimSet.play(colorAnim).with(mTimeAnim);
    mInternalAnimSet.start();
    if (mMenuItem != null) {
        mMenuItem.setActionView(mImageView);
    }
    for (AnimationControl ctrl : animationControls) {
        ctrl.start();
    }
    }

    public void end() {
    mTimeAnim.end();
    if (mMenuItem != null) {
        mMenuItem.setActionView(null);
    }
    }

    public void updateProgress(float progress) {
    for (AnimationControl ctrl : animationControls) {
        ctrl.updateProgress(progress);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
    for (AnimationControl ctrl : animationControls) {
        ctrl.updateState();
    }
    }
}
```

***AnimationControl.java***: Controls the progression of transition.

```
public class AnimationControl {
    private AnimatorSet mAnimSet;
    private Object target;
    private float start;
    private float end = 1.0f;
    private float progressWidth;
    private long time;
    private boolean started;
    private long mStartDelay;
    private long mDuration;
    private long mTotalDuration;

    public AnimationControl(AnimatorSet mAnimSet, float start, float end) {
    this(null, mAnimSet, start, end);
    }

    public AnimationControl(Object target, AnimatorSet mAnimSet, float start, float end) {
    for (Animator animator : mAnimSet.getChildAnimations()) {
        if (!(animator instanceof ValueAnimator)) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only ValueAnimator and its subclasses are supported");
        }
    }
    this.target = target;
    this.mAnimSet = mAnimSet;
    mStartDelay = mAnimSet.getStartDelay();
    mDuration = mAnimSet.getDuration();
    if (mAnimSet.getDuration() >= 0) {
        long duration = mAnimSet.getDuration();
        for (Animator animator : mAnimSet.getChildAnimations()) {
        animator.setDuration(duration);
        }
    } else {
        for (Animator animator : mAnimSet.getChildAnimations()) {
        long endTime = animator.getStartDelay() + animator.getDuration();
        if (mDuration < endTime) {
            mDuration = endTime;
        }
        }
    }
    mTotalDuration = mStartDelay + mDuration;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    progressWidth = Math.abs(end - start);
    }

    public void start() {
    if (target != null) {
        for (Animator animator : mAnimSet.getChildAnimations()) {
        animator.setTarget(target);
        }
    }
    }

    public void updateProgress(float progress) {
    if (start < end && progress >= start && progress <= end || start > end && progress >= end && progress <= start) {
        if (start < end) {
        time = (long) (mTotalDuration * (progress - start) / progressWidth);
        } else {
        time = (long) (mTotalDuration - mTotalDuration * (progress - end) / progressWidth);
        }
        time -= mStartDelay;
        if (time > 0) {
        started = true;
        }
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "updateState: " + mTotalDuration + ";" + time+"/"+start+"/"+end);
    } else {
        //forward
        if (start < end) {
        if (progress < start) {
            time = 0;
        } else if (progress > end) {
            time = mTotalDuration;
        }
        //backward
        } else if (start > end) {
        if (progress > start) {
            time = 0;
        } else if (progress > end) {
            time = mTotalDuration;
        }
        }
        started = false;
    }
    }

    public void updateState() {
    if (started) {
        for (Animator animator : mAnimSet.getChildAnimations()) {
        ValueAnimator va = (ValueAnimator) animator;
        long absTime = time - va.getStartDelay();
        if (absTime > 0) {
            va.setCurrentPlayTime(absTime);
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

***ProgressDrawerListener.java***: This listens for `DrawerLayout` state update and setup the required animation.

```
public class ProgressDrawerListener implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {
private final List<ProgressAnimator> mAnimatingMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();
private final Toolbar mToolbar;
private final ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout.DrawerListener mDrawerListener;
private MenuItemAnimation mMenuItemAnimation;
private Animation mAnimation;
private boolean started;
private boolean mOpened;
private Activity mActivity;
private boolean mInvalidateOptionOnOpenClose;

public ProgressDrawerListener(Toolbar mToolbar, ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle) {
    this.mToolbar = mToolbar;
    this.mDrawerToggle = mDrawerToggle;
}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
    mDrawerToggle.onDrawerOpened(view);
    clearAnimation();
    started = false;

    if (mDrawerListener != null) {
        mDrawerListener.onDrawerOpened(view);
    }
    mToolbar.getMenu().setGroupVisible(0, false); //TODO not always needed
    mOpened=true;
    mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    mDrawerToggle.onDrawerClosed(view);
    clearAnimation();
    started = false;

    if (mDrawerListener != null) {
        mDrawerListener.onDrawerClosed(view);
    }
    mOpened=false;
    mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int state) {
    mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(state);
    switch (state) {
        case DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING:
        case DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING:
            if (mAnimatingMenuItems.size() > 0 || started) {
                break;
            }
            started = true;

            setupAnimation();
            break;
        case DrawerLayout.STATE_IDLE:
            clearAnimation();
            started = false;
            break;
    }

    if (mDrawerListener != null) {
        mDrawerListener.onDrawerStateChanged(state);
    }
}

private void setupAnimation() {
    mToolbar.getMenu().setGroupVisible(0, true); //TODO not always needed
    mAnimatingMenuItems.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < mToolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View v = mToolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            int menuItemCount = 0;
            int childCount = ((ActionMenuView) v).getChildCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
                if (((ActionMenuView) v).getChildAt(j) instanceof ActionMenuItemView) {
                    menuItemCount++;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
                final View innerView = ((ActionMenuView) v).getChildAt(j);
                if (innerView instanceof ActionMenuItemView) {
                    MenuItem mMenuItem = ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getItemData();
                    ProgressAnimator offsetAnimator = new ProgressAnimator(mToolbar.getContext(), mMenuItem);

                    if(mMenuItemAnimation!=null) {
                        mMenuItemAnimation.setupAnimation(mMenuItem, offsetAnimator, j, menuItemCount);
                    }
                    if(mAnimation!=null) {
                        mAnimation.setupAnimation(offsetAnimator);
                    }

                    offsetAnimator.start();
                    mAnimatingMenuItems.add(offsetAnimator);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    onDrawerSlide(null, mOpened ? 1f : 0f);
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "setupAnimation: "+mAnimatingMenuItems.size()); //TODO
}

@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideOffset) {
    for (ProgressAnimator ani : mAnimatingMenuItems) {
        ani.updateProgress(slideOffset);
    }

    if(view==null) {
        return;
    }
    mDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(view, slideOffset);

    if (mDrawerListener != null) {
        mDrawerListener.onDrawerSlide(view, slideOffset);
    }
}

private void clearAnimation() {
    for (ProgressAnimator ani : mAnimatingMenuItems) {
        ani.end();
    }
    mAnimatingMenuItems.clear();
}

public void setDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener mDrawerListener) {
    this.mDrawerListener = mDrawerListener;
}

public MenuItemAnimation getMenuItemAnimation() {
    return mMenuItemAnimation;
}

public void setMenuItemAnimation(MenuItemAnimation mMenuItemAnimation) {
    this.mMenuItemAnimation = mMenuItemAnimation;
}

public Animation getAnimation() {
    return mAnimation;
}

public void setAnimation(Animation mAnimation) {
    this.mAnimation = mAnimation;
}

public void setmInvalidateOptionOnOpenClose(Activity activity, boolean invalidateOptionOnOpenClose) {
    mActivity=activity;
    mInvalidateOptionOnOpenClose = invalidateOptionOnOpenClose;
}

public interface MenuItemAnimation {

    public void setupAnimation(MenuItem mMenuItem, ProgressAnimator offsetAnimator, int itemIndex, int menuCount);
}

public interface Animation {

    public void setupAnimation(ProgressAnimator offsetAnimator);
}
```

}

**Set up in Activity**: The example code below switches between two different menu options between opened and closed state. Optionally add `offsetDrawerListener.setDrawerListener(DrawerListener)` if you need to have your own `DrawerListener`.:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //other init

    mProgressDrawerListener =new ProgressDrawerListener(toolbar, mDrawerToggle);
    mProgressDrawerListener.setmInvalidateOptionOnOpenClose(this, true);
    mOpenAnimation = new ProgressDrawerListener.MenuItemAnimation() {
        @Override
        public void setupAnimation(MenuItem mMenuItem, ProgressAnimator offsetAnimator, int itemIndex, int menuCount) {
            MainActivity.this.setupAnimation(true, offsetAnimator, itemIndex);
        }
    };
    mCloseAnimation = new ProgressDrawerListener.MenuItemAnimation() {
        @Override
        public void setupAnimation(MenuItem mMenuItem, ProgressAnimator offsetAnimator, int itemIndex, int menuCount) {
            MainActivity.this.setupAnimation(false, offsetAnimator, itemIndex);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mProgressDrawerListener);
}

//customize your animation here
private void setupAnimation(boolean open, ProgressAnimator offsetAnimator, int itemIndex) {
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "alpha", 1.0f, 0f),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "scaleX", 1.0f, 0f)
    );
    set.setStartDelay(itemIndex * 200);
    set.setDuration(1000 - itemIndex * 200); //not the actual time the animation will be played
    if(open) {
        offsetAnimator.addAnimatorSet(set, 0, 1);
    } else {
        offsetAnimator.addAnimatorSet(set, 1, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
    // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
    // decide what to show in the action bar.
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(findViewById(R.id.drawerList))) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
        mProgressDrawerListener.setMenuItemAnimation(
                mCloseAnimation);
    } else {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mProgressDrawerListener.setMenuItemAnimation(
                mOpenAnimation);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mProgressDrawerListener);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**menu_animation.xml**: This is to get the custom `ActionView` to have the same layout as the view used by `MenuIem`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/menu_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="@*android:dimen/action_button_min_width"
        android:padding="8dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: can you explain me how can I merge it with changing of menu items?

Comment: If you want to make it exactly like shown in the gif, I tried it and don't recommend it at all. It's not how the whole menu system was designed, requires you to update menu options in the middle of the transition, and most damning of all, none of Google's vast array of apps actually do this. However, if you mean changing menu items after transition, I should be able to whip up something for you. I had working code, but it's broken now :-/

Comment: @Siper updated answer, it switches menu options when the drawer is opened/closed.

Comment: can you direct me where should I look to extend MenuItem Transition to use it without Navigation Drawer (for example transition started by calling function)?

Comment: @Siper The easiest way is to use one of the provided adapters (Drawer, ViewPager, SlidingUpPanel) or write your own. What scenario do you have in mind?

Comment: I want change menu items with updating main activity's fragment (in my app this is activity with ListItem, and when I click on item, fragment are updated and shows details about that selected item. My goal is changing with fragment menu too: on fragment with listitem shows settings etc, on details shows for example sharing button, delete... ) . I'm looking now in MenuItemTransition class.

Comment: @Siper in this case the best method would be to create an "adapter" that translates the desired animation time to a [0..1] float value to be passed to ITransition. This is kinda of round about way of doing things since internally the [0..1] float value would then be translated to an integer value again. But it does make sense in the context of having a consistent method of animating/transiting View/MenuItem under different situations. I should be able to whip up an adapter doing exact that today or tomorrow, it does sound useful :P

Comment: @Siper Here's a new [adapter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj4usrxva8m3tj2/AnimationAdapter.java?dl=0) that works in my (limited) testing, try it out and let me know how it works. To setup: `mAnimationAdapter=new AnimationAdapter();`
        `mAnimationAdapter.setupOpenOption(this, new MenuOptionConfiguration(mShrinkOpen, R.menu.drawer));` To run: `mAnimationAdapter.startAnimation(duration);`

Comment: something going wrong, and transition not work. My Gist: https://gist.github.com/Siprah/7480d5b44e5f75b403c3 After clicking a button my menu items are just removing and nothing do more. Am I doing something wrong? And yes: I'm not professionally javadev, but I can't use custom adapters placed in my package. I must download library from Github, move source core into my android studio's project and place adapter into library's package. This is a bug?

Comment: @Siper sorry has been busy. Please update the library to 'com.github.kaichunlin.transition:core:0.8.3', download the newest sample app source code, and apply unreleased patch [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvct0re7krd7x4x/activity_drawer_menuitem.xml?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okkfhix3ded3vkw/DrawerMenuItemActivity.java?dl=0) to see how it can be used.

Answer (score 4):

I think I finally found your answer. This was way harder to find than I thought. If you take a look at this link: http://suhan.in/material-design-toolbar-animation/

The first one explains how this is done.

Below you find my own code snippet of how it could be done with only the menu items:

```
for(int i = 0; i < toolbarView.getChildCount(); i++) 
{
    final View v = toolbarView.getChildAt(i);

    if(v instanceof ActionMenuView) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildCount(); j++) 
        {
            final View innerView = ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildAt(j);

            if(innerView instanceof ActionMenuItemView) 
            {
                innerView.setTranslationY(-30);
                innerView.animate().setStartDelay(100 + (j * 10)).setDuration(200).translationY(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the animation for the Y-axis. You can also add the animation for size, which I think they do in the design guidelines. Also if you don't want them to start simultaniously, you can set startDelay and add extra like this: `setStartDelay(i * 10)`. This way each item starts the animation a little later. I already put this in the code snippet, but tweak it as how you would like it.

Comment: Yes, this works, but it needs a lot of improvement. @Siper only needs the action items to be animated, not the title and logo.

Comment: Yes it works to animate the menu items but it still doesn't address the main problem which is crossfading two menus

Comment: @Lamorak The other one was approved, so you could use that one. If you want to use mine I could find out for you how to do the crossfading. Let me know