# How to change the contents of actionbar using animations in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, menuitem

I want to change the contents of the actionbar when I select itens of a RecyclerView, so that it shows the menuitems to `delete` and `edit`, and the navigation icon to cancel the selection. This change of contents however, has to have an animation, like many apps do.

I've already checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445096/how-to-add-animation-while-actionbar-are-changing-their-content-with-appcompat) but it's a bit different from my goal (since I'm not using navigation drawer) and it's far too complicated + with not so good results.

The result should be something like this or any smooth animation:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an animation by setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`  in the toolbar's XML. I'm satisfied with how it looks even though I can't control it.